# How can I filter my data in Crystal Reports in C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have text fields where I can enter all my data, and when I click a button <kbd>print</kbd> it will directly go into the Crystal Report which is already filtered containing my data. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data as parameters to the Report. Bind the button click event to Generate the Report.

Comment: I assume, you are looking at a form, where you have a lot of textfields and the values entered into the textfields have to be passed to Crystal Reports. By Filter, if you mean only to display certain results based on the values passed from textfield, then write a formula field in the crystal report.

Comment: I would suggest that you provide with more detailed explanation on what you are doing, so that it would be easier to understand your problem.

Comment: i have another form which will i entered data and when i click a button to print that it will directly go in the other form containing the crystal report which is already filtered with my data