# How to filter Crystal Reports in C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How can I filter my entered data in one form that contains a text field into the 2nd form that contains the [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) viewer using C#?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263390/how-can-i-filter-my-data-in-crystal-reports-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Create a field in your Report and fill it programmatically before rendering the report. The report can filter on this field.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you need is something call parameterization in crystal report
http://www.dotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/SaifiFFC/CrystalReport07122007062723AM/CrystalReport.aspx